# How can I get rid of the small number near the YouTube desktop icon

Tags: youtube, app-icons

What does the small white number on orange background in the upper right corner of the YouTube desktop icon mean?

And how can I remove it?

[image: Android Desktop Screenshot]

Comment: You have 5 notifications on YouTube, open YouTube an view notifications or disable them trought YouTube app settings

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have notifications. You need to enter the app to make it dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Those number shows your YouTube Pending Notifications. 
To remove that, open the YouTube App, Goto **Activity--> Notifications-->** and the click on each notification. Now close the app. Your problem will be solved.